# Should I pass information inside Observer Events

Tags: java, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I have an Event `Login`. I plan to populate that event with information such as this:

```
// Class A.
Login login = new Login();
login.setUsername(userName);
observer.notifyEvent(login);
```

The idea is for class `B` to get this information.

Is this bad practice? If so why?

The only forseable problem is that some other part of the software will be listening to this for no reason. When in reality only one class should be getting the information.

The only advantage is that all my classes are connected to the Observer object, but not connected to each other. In other words, if I wanted to pass the username I would need to connect `A` and `B`. Which I would only do in extreme circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much of a problem. - However, you may want to include the "sender" of the event in the event object so that the listener can identify where it comes from and, if needed, can get further state information from the event source.

Answer (score 0):

The [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) allows you to decouple the source of the event from the consumers of an event.

This is generally a good idea,  even if you are only going to register one consumer.

However, I'll recommend you not to use the `java.util.Observer` which uses plain `java.lang.Object` as events, which means you must check the event object via `instanceof` and cast to the appropriate class.

I think its better to use an `Observer` or `Listener` implementation which supports generic types, such as  Spring's [ApplicationListener](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener.html) or Guava's [EventBus](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained) which allow you  to register Listener for events of particular class type, such as `Login.class` in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you probably need to dive a bit deeper into the original GoF book. For such a situation when a developer cares about different components that might be interested in different types of events the book offers the `subjects` collection that is maintained by the `ChangeManager`.

So when a component is interested in a specific type of event it passes a specific subject to the `Register` method so that this component won’t receive the updates for the events that represent a different subject. Additional advantage is the further decreasing of coupling.

Alternatively you might end up with building the system where any component that is plugged to the wire listens to all the events but that solution is too generic and adds lots of risks to the implementation (e.g. in the runtimes with automatic memory management like .NET the garbage collector won’t collect the subscriber while it is listening to any event – just because the ChangeManager still maintains a reference to it). It adds an additional responsibility to the subscriber - it has to do the additional filtering of events analyzing their type.

The rule of thumb is that you don’t need to subscribe for a **specific** event if you’re not interested to be notified when it occurs.

Referring to your example it is much better to introduce the `Login` subject and not to subscribe to it any component that is not interested in this specific subject.